# Printwriter: issues saving content of a text file in a one dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, printwriter

I am new to Java and I am using the PrintWriter class for the first time. I am supposed to create a text file with three rows and three columns, to split the strings on the white space and to save them in an array. Unfortunately, I am getting the wrong results and I am struggling to figure out what is happening. Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "Uebung_8.txt";
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    int cols = 4;
    int rows = 4;
    String[][] arr = new String[rows][cols];
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int zeile = 1; zeile < rows; zeile++) {
        for (int spalte = 1; spalte < cols; spalte++) {
            writer.print(arr[zeile][spalte] = "Zelle " + spalte + " ");
        }
        writer.println();
    }
    writer.close();
    String zeile;
    int controlZeile = 0;
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(fileName);
    String[][] newArray = new String[rows][cols];
    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
        zeile = fileScan.nextLine();
        newArray[controlZeile] = zeile.split("\\s");
        controlZeile++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray[0]));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray[1]));
    fileScan.close();
}
```

This is what I get on the text file Uebung_8.txt:

```
Zelle 1 Zelle 2 Zelle 3 
Zelle 1 Zelle 2 Zelle 3 
Zelle 1 Zelle 2 Zelle 3
```

First of all, the index was getting out of bounds all the time and therefore I have to set the value of cols and rows to 4, even though it is a very bad solution. Second, it seems that the scanner is not reading the content of the file and I get nulls as output, precisely:

```
[Uebung_8.txt]
[null, null, null, null]
```

What I should get:

```
Zelle 1Zelle 2Zelle 3 
Zelle 1Zelle 2Zelle 3
Zelle 1Zelle 2Zelle 3
```

Every hint would be really appreciated!

Comment: What your program does is quite pointless - writing to a file and after that, immediately reading it again. I assume this is for practice only?

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Since you are doing `zeile.split("\\s")`, you seem to want `[Zelle, 1, Zelle, 2, Zelle, 3]`, but then the inner arrays would have `col * 2` elements, whereas you have specified that the arrays should have `col` elements. (Note that doing this is unnecessary either way)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your usecase but some points in your code:

- first PrintWriter implements Closeable interface so you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
- in `Scanner` object creation you passed a string so the scanner will use that string as input try pass `Paths.get("Uebung_8.txt")` or `new Scanner(new File(filename)))` if you want to use `Uebung_8.txt` file as your input.

  ```java
  String fileName = "Uebung_8.txt";
  int cols = 3;
  int rows = 3;
  String[][] arr = new String[rows][cols];
  try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName)) {
      for (int zeile = 0; zeile < rows; zeile++) {
          for (int spalte = 0; spalte < cols; spalte++) {
              arr[zeile][spalte] = "Zelle " + spalte + "\t";
              writer.write(arr[zeile][spalte]);
          }
          writer.println();
      }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String zeile;
  int controlZeile = 0;
  Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(Paths.get("Uebung_8.txt"));
  String[][] newArray = new String[rows][cols];
  while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
      zeile = fileScan.nextLine();
      newArray[controlZeile] = zeile.split("\t");
      controlZeile++;
  }
  ```